# TYPO3 and Router ExtDirect Invalid security token

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I know there is several posts on the Internet about this. But none of them solves my problem.

I use FireFox when working in TYPO3 Backend and I never see the pink boxes, but my customer uses Internet Explorer and right now she can't work in TYPO3 because of the small pink boxes saying

Router
ExtDirect: Invalid Security token

What triggers these errors and what can I do about it?

At the bootom of http://wiki.typo3.org/ExtDirect it says something about a small change that fixes it, but where should I change these lines?

I hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `$pageRenderer->addExtDirectCode();` in your backend module, assuming that the passed instance of the page renderer is inside the `$pageRenderer` variable.

This makes sure that the required code for the ExtDirect call is added.

Your customer should get a bunch of `JavaScript` errors too.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by *the page renderer is side the ``$pageRenderer`` variable*?

Comment: I do not know your source code unless you share it with me. You get an instance of the page rendered passed on object creation or you cat fetch the singleton by calling: `$this->doc = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Backend\\Template\\DocumentTemplate');` and then `$this->doc->getPageRenderer();` or by calling `$pageRenderer = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\Page\PageRenderer');`

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering what *is side* means, but I guess you meant *is inside*.

Comment: hey, I am running in the same issue and I am even new to typo3, I don't know where to add exactly that line , I am using typo3 4.5

Comment: This is only relevant for self-written extensions that include custom JS code.